# Geometric Distribution Problem (cant find the answer for my life)

Tags: binomial-distribution

I must be missing something on this problem, so here is the question:

An NFL quarterback's completion rate is **70%**. Find the probability that the quarterback completes **15 of 30** passes during the game.

I know its a geometric distribution problem since it has no set number of trials, and that there are two or three numbers I'm dealing with here, and that's where I stop cause I can't figure it out. Any ideas?

Comment: Never mind I found the answer for this question (maybe a referral problem??)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a Geometric Distribution.

What we are looking at is the number of successes in $n$ trials. In this case, its the number of complete passes in $30$ attempts. This is a Binomial Distribution.

So we want the probability of getting $15$ successes out of $30$ trials with $p = 0.7$

The resting probability may look small, but remember you are calculating the probability of **exactly** $15$, not more or not less

Comment: Thank you! I just realized that this midterm assignment had multiple kinds of distribution problems on it. Again, thank you!